# Magento 1.9.0.1: where to find getStoreConfig variable

Tags: php, magento

I am working with an existing magento instance and somewhere in the code there is this:

```
 $url = Mage::getStoreConfig('companyname/joomlapath/url');
```

What I'm trying to do is change the value of this variable. I searched the entire code for "joomlapath" but there doesn't seem to be a definition anywhere. And I search the backend, but I seem to be too stupid to find this.

Any hints where I might be able to change this value? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

login to `admin panel` go to `system -> configuration` in side bar  check the extension `configuration` there you will find the field with name url or something similar. change that field values.

**second solution** got to your database

find table `core_config_data`

and **search** `companyname/joomlapath/url` in `path column`

Comment: I tried that but I cannot find anything in the sidebar resembling companyname or url or joomlapath

Comment: did you check in main menu for the extension sub menu and configuration link?

Answer (score 1):

1. Review you **etc/system.xml** file of your module.
2. Search the keywords companyname,joomlapath and url one by one.
3. If system.xml not present in **etc** directory then look in
   **etc/config.xml** and search the same keywords as above.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: I searched the entire project for "joomlapath" and "companyname" - joomlapath returns nothing except some getStoreConfig calls and companyname returns only other modules from the company